# Two objects having same hashcode means they are referring to same object ..right?

Tags: scala

Being new to Scala, I have created an Object (singleton). and assinged two different variables to that object as shown below. Both of them show me the same hashcode. Because "School" is a singleton. Is that right?

```
 object Main extends  App{

 //we can import within the method as well .
 import Scala_DemoSingletonPackage._

  //See both the objeccts have same hashcode.
  println("The hasshcode for first object is " + aSchool.hashCode())
  println("The Hashcode from second object is " + bSchool.hashCode())

}

object School {


  def Printwhateveryouwant(input:String) {
     println(s"This is a singleton object  $input")


 }
```

Comment: Yes, there will only be one instance of the School object so all variables the object is assigned to will have the same hashcode.

Answer (score 5):

There are *two* misconceptions in your statement:

1. You assume that an equal `hashCode` implies object equality. That is not true. In fact, it *cannot possibly be true* because there are only finitely many hashes but infinitely many objects, so there *must* be an infinite number of objects with the same `hashCode`. An *unequal* `hashCode` means that the objects are *unequal*, but an *equal* `hashCode` tells you precisely nothing at all. However, the "other direction" is true: if two objects are equal, then they have the same `hashCode`.
2. You assume that equality implies identity. That is also not true. The fact that two objects are equal does *not* mean that they are also identical. Again, the "other direction" is (trivially) true: an object is equal to itself.

Note: all of these actually depend on properly implemented methods, of course. It is perfectly possible to write an equality method that violates reflexivity, for example. It's just that when you do something like that, you lose the guarantees Scala gives you.

So, you *cannot* conclude from the fact the two `hashCode`s are equal that the two objects are equal. And even if you *could* conclude that, you *still* cannot conclude from the fact the two objects are equal that they are actually one and the same object.

Nonetheless, that is true: there exists only one instance of a singleton object, that's why it is called a *singleton object*. So, your two references *must* refer to the same object, for the simple reason that there is only one object to begin with. However, the test you used to arrive at that conclusion is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Two objects having the same hashcode does **not** mean they are equal due to the nature of hashing (unless you have a perfect hash function that is).  However, if two objects are equal, then they **will** have the same hashcode.

In scala, if you'd like to check if objects are equal you can use the following:

```
aSchool eq bSchool
```

Comment: Useful addition to your answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)#In_theoretical_computer_science

Comment: Another useful addition: `eq` is only equality, `eq` means reference equality, meaning the objects are not only equals (as in have the same internal instance values), they are actually the *same* object.

Answer (score 1):

If two references refer to the same instance, selecting `hashCode` will invoke that method on the instance.

It's not relevant that two variables are used, and it's not relevant whether the referent is a `Singleton`.

```
scala> val x = new AnyRef
x: Object = java.lang.Object@21fdfefc

scala> val y = x
y: Object = java.lang.Object@21fdfefc

scala> x.hashCode == y.hashCode
res0: Boolean = true
```